# Change UDP traffic on the fly. Searching for Network device

Tags: networking, router, iptables, udp, traffic-filtering

I have one specific hardware which generates UDP traffic but due to one single issue inside the UDP data part, another device can't correctly work and skip UDP packets.

Please, can you suggest to me some Hardware Network devices (like managed Switch or Router) that can CHANGE UDP packets or recreate based on some rules.

I would like to use a standalone network device and not a regular PC.

p.s
UDP traffic speed 10Mbit, after UDP MITM :) speed, should not be changed.

**Update**

Thanks "A.B" for the comment found a solution based on nftables keyword.

https://serverfault.com/questions/988309/filter-on-bytes-in-udp-payload-using-nftables

Comment: What change are you looking for in the UDP?  Would a NAT based router do what you need?

Comment: I need to change two bytes of data inside the UDP. Not in the UDP header but inside data section

Answer (score 2):

To do more than header changes (i.e., routing the packet) on a standalone network device, you will need a computer with an operating system.  However, you might be able to find a small armbian device or replace the operating system on a router and add a new application.

Then you will have to find a way to intercept the packet and modify it.  The easiest way would be to use a proxy method; for instance, you could write a service that receives packets sent to it and then sends them back out to the target device after making the changes.  In this configuration, it wouldn't even have to have two ports -- it could resend the packet out on the same port.

However, if you want this to be completely transparent (rather than an intentional man in the middle device), you will need to set it up as a bridge or a router and intercept the packet which would be a lot more work.  As mentioned in a comment, nftables might be able to make simple changes.

Comment: Thank you I understand that I could use Raspberry or such but I would like to get maximum speed and minimal work :)
And therefore I'm searching for some device already available where I can write small script and "Voi la" :)

Comment: 10Mbit is pretty slow, a pi can do that fine.  Did you perhaps mean 10G instead?

Comment: 10Mbit, all correct

Comment: Pi 2 can do half of 1G so it should do 10M fine.

Comment: note: usually *iptables* (in the question's tag) can't do this, it can only detect these two bytes (using u32 match) but not change them. *nftables* can change them if it's easy to locate (eg: fixed position) using `@th... set ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about nftables, yes, it's in a fixed position.

Comment: @A.B Does NFTABLES will update UDP checksum after change?